# React Query fetches the path, but doesn't display the image

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I have an issue, where I try to fetch my images from the backend, here is the ReactQuery code:

```
export const useGetProductImagesByProductId = (productId: string) =>
    useQuery({
        queryKey: ['productImages', productId],
        queryFn: async () =>
        (await (await apiClient.get)<ProductImage[]>(`api/products/images/getImages/${productId}`)).data,
    })
```

The thing is that I fetch them separatelly from my products, the image url is fetched, but not rendered?

I render my products in the ProductItem Component:

```
function ProductItem({product}: {product: Product}){
    const { data: images, isLoading: imagesLoading, error: imagesError } = useGetProductImagesByProductId(product.productId);

    if (imagesLoading) return <div>Loading images...</div>;
    if (imagesError) return <div>Error loading images: {imagesError.message}</div>;

    const imageSrc = images && images.length > 0 ? images[0].imageUrl : '';

    return( 
        <Card>
            <Link to={'/product/' + product.productId}>
                <img src={imageSrc} alt={product.name} className='product-image'/>
            </Link>
            <Card.Body>
                <Link to={`/product/${product.productId}`}>
                    <Card.Title>{product.name}</Card.Title>
                </Link>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
        
    )
}
```

If I input the url directly in the `img` tag it works correctly:

`<img src={"http://localhost:5045/Upload/Product/abeb7b1e-6705-454c-3316-08dc36b5c832/image.png"} alt={product.name} className='product-image'/>`

**EDIT 1**

I tested the array, `images` returns the entire array, `images[0]` returns `undefined`, `images[0].urlPath` also returns undefined, I have a temporary solution:

`<img src={String(images && images[0])} alt={product.name} className='product-image'/>`

**EDIT 2**
The ProductImage type looks like this:

```
export type ProductImage = {
    imageUrl: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a timing issue.
Try this

```
{
    images && <Card>
    <Link to={'/product/' + product.productId}>
      <img src={images[0].imageUrl} alt={product.name} className='product-image' />
    </Link>
    <Card.Body>
      <Link to={`/product/${product.productId}`}>
        <Card.Title>{product.name}</Card.Title>
      </Link>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
}
```

Comment: Tested out your code, thank you for your answer, but I think the issue is with my `.imageUrl`, its `undefined`

Comment: Does imageUrl exist in the array?

Comment: No it doesn't, which is weird because I defined the type, I'll edit the question to add the type

Comment: Could you please log your array to the console? It's possible that the names or fields in the array don't match those in your database.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was rather simple, the query returned a json instead of a string and substituted it in the `<img src="">`, it couldn't convert to imageUrl because the JSON contained just the string and not a correctly formated object.